# Regex - find anagrams and sub-anagrams

Tags: regex, anagram

I have a pool of characters and I want to match all the words which are anagrams of those chars or of a subset of those chars using a regular expression.

Example: given the string "ACNE" the regex should give me these results:

- ACNE  [T]
- CENA  [T]
- CAN   [T]
- CAAN  [F]
- CANEN [F]

I've tried this solution `/b[acne]{1,4}/b` but it accepts multiple repetitions of single chars.
What can I do to take each char at most one time?

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this. I suggest you to use String Library of whatever language you are doing this in.

Comment: Check this answer, if you want to hammer a nail with screwdriver: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14383513/1400768 Or you can check other answers. It is probably duplicate of the question I linked to, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383119/check-if-string-is-subset-of-a-bunch-of-characters-regex/14383513

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sub-anagrams of the word "acne" are the words that

- consist only of the letters `acne`
- do not contain `a` more than once
- do not contain `c` more than once
- do not contain `n` more than once
- do not contain `e` more than once

Compiling this into a regex:

```
^(?!.*a.*a)(?!.*c.*c)(?!.*n.*n)(?!.*e.*e)[acne]*$
```

Test: [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E(%3F!.*a.*a)(%3F!.*c.*c)(%3F!.*n.*n)(%3F!.*e.*e)%5Bacne%5D*%24&input=acne%0Aean%0Adean%0Anne%0Acan%0A)

Alternatively, since "acne" does not contain any letter more than once, the sub-anagrams of the word "acne" are the words that

- consist only of the letters `acne`
- do not contain any letter more than once.

Compiling this into a regex:

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[acne]*$
```

Test: [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E(%3F!.*(.).*%5C1)%5Bacne%5D*%24&input=acne%0Aean%0Adean%0Anne%0Acan%0A)

Note: the sub-anagrams of the word "magmoid" can be matched as

```
^(?!.*([agoid]).*\1)(?!(.*m){3})[magoid]*$
```

(do not contain any of `agoid` more than once, and do not contain `m` more than twice)

Comment: Note that this is only possible if you assume the number of occurrences of the characters are equal. It can be modified a bit to accommodate the case above.

Comment: @nhahtdh 'since "acne" does not contain any letter more than once'; there is no such restriction for the first approach.

Comment: I'm talking about second approach. Yes, there is no restriction on the first approach.

Comment: @useless the point of the regex is to show, by example, how to build a regex for any specific word. The second regex shows how to do that for strings with repeated letters. It is expected that the reader can extrapolate from the information given. Can you?

Comment: but, how about letter repetition, how can you use that regex to match for example: doom as an anagram of mood?

Comment: @useless the second regex (and description) shows how to handle letters with repetition. Should I elaborate on how to optimise the regex if multiple letters have the same number of max. repetitions, or how to extrapolate from the second example?

Comment: @useless extrapolating from the magmoid example, `mood` would be `^(?!.*([md]).*\1)(?!(.*o){3})[mod]*$`

Answer (score 0):

**CODE TO FIND NUMBER OF ANAGRAMS OF A WORD IN A GIVEN STRING USING REGULAR REXPRESSION**

***Fork the below repository for java, DataStructure, Algorithms, and Company Interview Questions Practices. Please feel free to contribute to the Repository***

https://github.com/arpans2112/techsqually-java8-best-practices/blob/master/src/com/techsqually/java/library/util/regularexpression/anagramStrings.java

```
package com.techsqually.java.library.util.regularexpression;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class anagramStrings {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int count = findAnagramsInAGivenStrings("arpan","Hi arpan Aarpn we are testing rapan rranp anagram");
        System.out.println(count);
    }


    /**
     * <p> Use to find the number of anagrams of a word in a Given String</p>
     * @param : word : is the word for which you want to find the anagrams
     * @param : givenString : is the string in which you want to find the anagrams of word given
     * @return : total number of anagrams of the word passed
     *  
     *  all words in which each character count is same but their order can be different 
     *  e.g arpan and rapan are anagrams 
     *  
     * @output of above given example is 3, "arpan" , "Aarpn" and rapan are anagrams of arpan
     * */
    public static int findAnagramsInAGivenStrings(String word, String givenString){

        word = word.toLowerCase();
        givenString = givenString.toLowerCase();
        HashMap<String,Integer> numberOfAnnagrams = new HashMap<>();
       Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[" + word + "]{" + word.length() + "}").matcher(givenString);

       int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find()){

                 char[] matchWordArray = matcher.group().toCharArray();
                 char[] givenWordArray = word.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(matchWordArray);
            Arrays.sort(givenWordArray);

            if (Arrays.equals(matchWordArray,givenWordArray)) count++;
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```