# Create Regex search string with Regex in google sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I want to know if there is a way that I can use regex to create a regex search string for anagrams.

Related to this post:
[Regex - find anagrams and sub-anagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561614/regex-find-anagrams-and-sub-anagrams)

I've created [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/bieblebom.com/spreadsheets/d/13PL0drijqAT-f156F4DxQEtZO4Y5oGWX7rxnDxzCduw/edit?usp=sharing) with the word database

The regex to search for anagrams of acne is : `"^(?!.*a.*a)(?!.*c.*c)(?!.*n.*n)(?!.*e.*e)[acne]*$"` (from the aforementioned stackoverflow question).

I would like to use regexreplace to get from "acne" (or bacon or whatever string of letters to get to) `"^(?!.*<letter1>.*<letter1>)<repeat for each letter>[<letterstring>]*$"`?

If tried `regexreplace("acne",".",".*")` but that returns `.*.*.*.*` obviously. And what I was looking for is `.*a.*c.*n.*e` to then from there extrapolate further to get to `"^(?!.*a.*a)(?!.*c.*c)(?!.*n.*n)(?!.*e.*e)[acne]*$"`

Obviously I'd love it solve the multiletter dilemmas too: `^(?!.*([agoid]).*\1)(?!(.*m){3})[magoid]*$` but not sure how easy this will be with repeat letters.

Comment: Can you share the spreadsheet please?

Comment: Sorry I thought I did.  It's shared now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
="^(?!.*" & 
  JOIN(")(?!.*", 
       ArrayFormula(SPLIT(
         REGEXREPLACE(A1, 
                      "(\w)", "$1~"), 
         "~") & ".*" & 
       SPLIT(
         REGEXREPLACE(A1, 
                      "(\w)", "$1~"), 
         "~"))) & 
 ")[" & A1 & "]*$"
```

F1: `REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(\w)", "$1~"),` puts a tilde as a separator between every letter

F2: `SPLIT(<F1>, "~")` splits the word into an array

F3: `ARRAYFORMULA(<F2> & ".*" & <F2>)` creates an array of `<letter_i>.*<letter_i>`

F4: `JOIN(")(?!.*", <F3>)` joins the array together with the needed separators

`"^(?!.*" & <F4> & ")[" & A1 & "]*$"` appends the beginning and the end.

## Edit

At that point you might as well check

```
= JOIN(, SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(\w)", "$1~"), "~")))) = 
  JOIN(, SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B1, "(\w)", "$1~"), "~"))))
```

Comment: Wow dude if I can give you 1000 upvotes I would! This is amazing. And not just the regex, the sheets functions too. I must read up more on Regex.