# How do I write a command line that uses egrep to find an anagram?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I am thinking about writing a command for an anagram.

for example, floss.

i am starting with egrep[floss]{5}. the problem here is that the number of times a letter appears can possibly be more than once. how do I pipe this command into another one that could solve the problem?

thank you so much.

egrep[floss]{5} | egrep -v

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex - find anagrams and sub-anagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561614/regex-find-anagrams-and-sub-anagrams)

Comment: From the duplicate link: "Regex is not the right tool for this.".  You're looking for any sequence of letters that contains exactly the set of letters given.  That sounds like comparing a sorted set of characters, not a regex.

Comment: How did you get on with the answers you received?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a key function, which is to say a function that returns the same string for words that are anagrams, but different strings for words that aren't.

For example, you could sort the letters.

```bash
perl -e'
   use v5.14;
   sub key { join "", sort { $a cmp $b } split //, $_[0] }
   my $word = shift;
   my $key = key( $word );
   while ( <> ) {
      chomp;
      say if key( $_ ) eq $key;
   }
' floss /usr/share/dict/words
```

Output:

```
floss
```

No anagrams.

But provide `brief` and you get

```
brief
fiber
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind my implementing your excellent idea in a different language. Please accept my imitation as flattery

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @ikegami's excellent insight about sorting the letters, and using `grep` to try to be a bit closer to the question's constraints, hopefully you can see that `fiber` and `brief` produce the same output:

```
grep -o . <<< brief | sort
b
e
f
i
r
```

and:

```
grep -o . <<< fiber | sort
b
e
f
i
r
```

---

The `grep -o .` is just picking out each letter on its own line. The `.` matches any character and the `-o` causes `grep` to *only* output the matching character.

The `<<<` submits the word following it to `stdin` of `grep`. Note that this is a *"bash-ism"*, and will not work in other shells, where you would need to use `echo finer | grep -o . | sort`

---

If you want to compare two strings this way, you can use *"process substitution"*, which substitutes the output of a command so it looks like a file to another command. So, it looks like this if you are using `diff` for comparing the outputs of two commands:

```
diff <(command1) <(command2)
```

In your case, the command would look like this:

```
# "brief" is anagram of "fiber"
cmp <(grep -o . <<< brief | sort) <(grep -o . <<< fiber | sort)

# "finer" is not anagram of "fiber"
cmp <(grep -o . <<< finer | sort) <(grep -o . <<< fiber | sort)
/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62 differ: byte 1, line 1
```

So, hopefully you can see there is no output when the words are anagrams, and an error message and different exit status when they are not.