# How can check anagram strings in C#

Tags: c#, string

Given two strings A and B, check if they are anagrams.

*Two strings are said to be anagrams, if one string can be obtained by rearranging the letters of another.*

Examples of anagrams are

- `dog, god`
- `abac, baac`
- `123, 312`

`abab, aaba` and `dab, baad` are not anagrams.

**INPUT :**

First line of the input is the number of test cases T.
It is followed by T lines, each line has two space separated strings A and B;

**OUTPUT**

For each test case, print "YES" if they are anagrams, otherwise print "NO". (without quotes)

**Constraints**

1. 1 <= T <= 10
2. A and B both contain only lower case latin letters 'a' to 'z' and
   digits 0 to 9.
3. Length of each string A and B does not exceed 5*10^5 (500000)

`

```
Sample Input            Sample Output
------------------------------------
3                           YES
abcd bcda                   NO
bad daa                     YES
a1b2c3 abc123               NO
```

How can we do this ?

```
bool anagramChecker(string first, string second)
{
    if(first.Length != second.Length)
        return false;

    if(first == second)
        return true;//or false: Don't know whether a string counts as an anagram of itself

    Dictionary<char, int> pool = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach(char element in first.ToCharArray()) //fill the dictionary with that available chars and count them up
    {
        if(pool.ContainsKey(element))
            pool[element]++;
        else
            pool.Add(element, 1);
    }
    foreach(char element in second.ToCharArray()) //take them out again
    {
        if(!pool.ContainsKey(element)) //if a char isn't there at all; we're out
            return false;
        if(--pool[element] == 0) //if a count is less than zero after decrement; we're out
            pool.Remove(element);
    }
    return pool.Count == 0;
}
```

Comment: so this code is not working??

Comment: See [Need help expanding on an anagram regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156431/need-help-expanding-on-an-anagram-regex).

Comment: Cheater method is to sort characters and compare resulting sequences.

Comment: See [*Anagrams* at Rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/mw/index.php?title=Anagrams).

Comment: They are anagrams, not palindromes..

Comment: Honestly I think your solution is better than those suggested below.

Comment: [Umair M's answer down below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56172350/4271117) is the only one that works without the "time limited exceeded" issue.

Answer (score 22):

Is this your solution?

```
string a = "abcd";
string b = "bcda"; // bad daa a1b2c3 abc123

string aa = String.Concat(a.OrderBy(c => c));
string bb = String.Concat(b.OrderBy(c => c));

if (aa == bb)
{
     Console.WriteLine("YES");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("NO");
}
```

or shorter

```
if (String.Concat(a.OrderBy(c => c)).Equals(String.Concat(b.OrderBy(c => c))) ...
```

Comment: Concise but not very efficient? (O n log n?)

Comment: No, it is not his solution and his solution is better.

Comment: You can do the same thing even shorter: var isAnagram = a.OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEqual(b.OrderBy(c => c));

Comment: I did no check for 500k strings, because I do not believe it is a real live setting

Comment: for big strings I´ll test something on the Weekend

Comment: @Rawling You have to do at least O(n). You can do O(n), but the space will double. Example: Go through both strings and store letter - count in a dictionary: aabc => 2a, 1b, 1c;   caba => 2a; 1b; 1;

Answer (score 11):

There's the fast way and the simple way:

```
void Test()
{
    string a = "abccabccabccabccabccabccabccabccabccabccabccabccabccabccabccabcc";
    string b = "bcacbcacbcacbcacbcacbcacbcacbcacbcacbcacbcacbcacbcacbcacbcacbcac";

    IsAnagramSimple(a, b);
    IsAnagramFast(a, b);
}


private bool IsAnagramSimple(string a, string b)
{
    return a.OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEqual(b.OrderBy(c => c));
}

private bool IsAnagramFast(string a, string b)
{
    if (a.Length != b.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var aFrequency = CalculateFrequency(a);
    var bFrequency = CalculateFrequency(b);

    foreach (var key in aFrequency.Keys)
    {
        if (!bFrequency.ContainsKey(key)) return false;
        if (aFrequency[key] != bFrequency[key]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private Dictionary<char, int> CalculateFrequency(string input)
{
    var frequency = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        if (!frequency.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            frequency.Add(c, 0);
        }
        ++frequency[c];
    }
    return frequency;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public bool IsAnagram(string s1,string s2)
{
  if (s1.Length != s2.Length)
     return false;
  var s1Array = s1.ToLower().ToCharArray();
  var s2Array = s2.ToLower().ToCharArray();

  Array.Sort(s1Array);
  Array.Sort(s2Array);

  s1 = new string(s1Array);
  s2 = new string(s2Array);

  return s1 == s2;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to check if first one contains a char inside second one. then remove that char from first one until no more characters left.

```
    private bool IsAnagram(string a, string b)
    {
        if (a.Length != b.Length) return false;
        List<char> list1 = a.ToList();
        List<char> list2 = b.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            // try to remove list 1 item from list 2
            // if didn't find any thing to remove. so they are not anagram
            if (!list2.Remove(list1[i])) return false;
        }
        return true; // loop finished successfully. they are anagram
    }
```

Note that the [`List<T>.Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns a bool that specifies if the method was able to remove anything or not.

You can do this all in one line Linq.

```
List<char> list = "god".ToList();

bool isAnagram = "dog".All(ch => list.Remove(ch));
```

The Linq method `All<char>(Func<char,bool>)` will perform the delegate until the `Func<char,bool>` returns false or until end of query. if the Func return false then `All` returns false too. otherwise it will return true.

Comment: For Linq approach will not work correctly in cases "ab" and "a". Since they don't check the same length, please check sir.

Comment: I think you should keep the first condition `if(a.Length != b.Length) return false;` for linq approach too. @jack.pop

Answer (score 4):

Below is an algorithm without sorting two arrays. Assuming ContainsKey, Add, Remove methods of Dictionary are O(1) then the time complexity for the algorithm is O(N) rather than O(nlogn) for those using Sort.

```
static bool anagram(string s1, string s2)
    {
        if (s1.Length != s2.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Dictionary<char, int> bucket = new Dictionary<char, int>(50); 
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
        {               
            if (s1[i] == s2[i]) continue;

            for (int j = -1; j < 2; j = j + 2)
            {
                var aOrb = j == -1 ? s1[i] : s2[i];
                if (bucket.ContainsKey(aOrb))
                {
                    bucket[aOrb] += j;
                    if (bucket[aOrb] == 0)
                    {
                        bucket.Remove(aOrb);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    bucket.Add(aOrb, j);
                }
            }
        }

        return bucket.Count == 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need this line `bucket[aOrb] += j;`?

Comment: The idea is to use a dictionary to find different characters in the two strings. In the loop, we get two characters: one from s1 and another one from s2. Then for characters from s1 we add -1 to the corresponding dictionary entry and +1 for the characters from s2. If the result is 0, then we remove the entry from the dictionary. It is also possible to not remove the entry from the dictionary but, in the end, check the dictionary so it does not have any none zero entries.

Answer (score 3):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsAnagram(
            "tom marvolo riddle",
            "i am lord voldemort"));
    }
    static bool IsAnagram(string word, string dest)
    {
        var w = WordSpliter(word);
        var d = WordSpliter(dest);
        return w.Count == d.Count && w.Count == w.Where(x => d.Contains(x)).ToList().Count;
    }
    static List<(char Key, int Count)> WordSpliter(string word)
    {
        return word.Replace(" ", "").ToLower().GroupBy(c => c).Select(x => (
           x.Key,
           Count: x.Count()
       )).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a constraint of limited time, this is a better/efficient solution:

```
bool CheckAnagram(string str1, string str2)
{
    if(str1.Length != str2.Length)
        return false;

    if(str1 == str2)
        return true;

    // based on 128 ASCII characeters. 
    // You can change the paramter depending on requirement
    int charLength = 128; 

    int[] counter = new int[charLength];

    for(int i=0; i<str1.Length; i++)
    {
        counter[str1[i]-'a']++;
        counter[str2[i]-'a']--;
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < charLength; c++) 
    {
        if(counter[c] != 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is accepted on codestandard.net

```
public bool IsAnagram(string one, string two)
    {
        if(one.ToLower().Equals(two.ToLower()))
            return true;
    
        var array1 = one.ToCharArray();
        var array2 = two.ToCharArray();
        
        Array.Sort(array1);
        Array.Sort(array2);
        
        return array1 == array2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static bool IsAnagram(this string a, string b)
    {
        //check the length are not same ? not Anagram
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;

        // check both the strings are same ? Angram
        if (a == b)
            return true;

        // Sort the characters alphabetically and compare them to one another.
        return a.OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEqual(b.OrderBy(c => c));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will check for anagram for exactly 1 pass (*O(Cn) where C = 1*)

```
    public static bool IsAnagram(string s1, string s2) {
        if (s1.Length != s2.Length)
            return false;

        int i = -1;

        var chars = new Dictionary<char, int> ();

        Func <char, int, int, int> updateCount = (c, side, pdiff) => {
            int count = 0;
            chars.TryGetValue (c, out count);
            var newCount = count + side;
            chars[c] = newCount;
            if (count == 0)
                return pdiff + 1;
            else if (newCount == 0)
                return pdiff - 1;
            else
                return pdiff;
        };

        int diff = 0;
        foreach (var c1 in s1) {
            i++;
            var c2 = s2 [i];

            if (c1 == c2)
                continue;

            diff = updateCount(c1, 1, diff);
            diff = updateCount(c2, -1, diff);
        }

        return diff == 0;
    }
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string s1 = "asd";
        string s2 = "ads";

        Console.WriteLine (IsAnagram(s1, s2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### For case insensitive you can try this:

```
public bool IsAnagram(string firstString, string secondString)
        {
            List<char> firstlist = new List<char>();
            firstlist.AddRange(firstString);

            List<char> secondlist = new List<char>();
            secondlist.AddRange(secondString);

            if (secondlist.Count != firstlist.Count)
            {
                return false;
            }

            while (firstlist.Count != 0 && secondlist.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var sec in secondlist)
                {
                    foreach (var fir in firstlist)
                    {
                        if (char.ToUpperInvariant(sec) == char.ToUpperInvariant(fir))
                        {
                            firstlist.Remove(fir);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    secondlist.Remove(sec);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (firstlist.Count == secondlist.Count)
                return true;
            return false;          
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
static bool isAnagrams(string str1,string st)
{
    string str1 = "reaad";
    string str2 = "Daaer";
    char[] t = str1.ToCharArray();
    var kt = t.Distinct();
    string pattern = @"e";
    // Create a Regex  
    Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);
    Console.WriteLine(rg.Match(str1).Value);
    foreach (var item in kt)
    {
        string pat = item.ToString();
        Regex r = new Regex(pat,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (r.Matches(str1).Count != r.Matches(str2).Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] fArr = new char[First.Length];
    char[] sArr = new char[Second.Length];
    fArr = First.ToLower().ToCharArray();
    sArr= Second.ToLower().ToCharArray();

    if (fArr.Length == sArr.Length)
    {
       Array.Sort(fArr);
        Array.Sort(sArr);
    }



    return new string(fArr) == new string(sArr) ? true : false;
```

Comment: you should add a little more context to your answer instead of just posting the code.

Comment: How is this any different from the already [provided answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56711575/59081)?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for a List of Strings (Not just two Strings).
If you are interested in it or any other one, you can use it.

Given an array of strings, remove each string that is an anagram of an earlier string, then return the remaining array in stored order.

```
private static List<string> GencoAnagrams(List<string> textList)
    {
        var listCount = textList.Count;
        if (listCount == 1) return textList;

        for (var j = 1; j < listCount; j++)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < j; i++)
            {
                if (string.Concat(textList[j].OrderBy(x => x)).Equals(string.Concat(textList[i].OrderBy(y => y))))
                {
                    textList.RemoveAt(j);
                    --listCount;
                    --j;
                    if (listCount == 1) break;
                }
            }
            if (listCount == 1) break;
        }
        return textList;
    }
```

I also thanks "[Thomas Krojer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244165/thomas-krojer)" for his Answer, it was very helpful for me at first.

> if (String.Concat(a.OrderBy(c => c)).Equals(String.Concat(b.OrderBy(c
>   => c))) ...

Answer (score -1):

```
class Anagrams
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // 1
        // Read and sort dictionary
        var d = Read();

        // 2
        // Read in user input and show anagrams
        string line;
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Show(d, line);
        }
    }

    static Dictionary<string, string> Read()
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // Read each line
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("enable1.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Alphabetize the line for the key
                // Then add to the value string
                string a = Alphabetize(line);
                string v;
                if (d.TryGetValue(a, out v))
                {
                    d[a] = v + "," + line;
                }
                else
                {
                    d.Add(a, line);
                }
            }
        }
        return d;
    }

    static string Alphabetize(string s)
    {
        // Convert to char array, then sort and return
        char[] a = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Sort(a);
        return new string(a);
    }

    static void Show(Dictionary<string, string> d, string w)
    {
        // Write value for alphabetized word
        string v;
        if (d.TryGetValue(Alphabetize(w), out v))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

O(n) Solution

```
public bool Anagram(string s , string p)
{
    char[] dS = s.ToCharArray();
    char[] dP = p.ToCharArray();
    Array.Sort(dS);
    Array.Sort(dP);
    string rS = new string(dS);
    string rP = new string(dP);
    return rS == rP;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [answer] section.  
Now, are you sure this solution is O(n)? What's the complexity of the sorting methods?

Comment: Not different from already [given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56711575/59081) answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
string one = "aabba";
        string two = "bbaaa";
        int check = 0;

        List<char> oneList = one.ToCharArray().ToList();
        List<char> twoList = two.ToCharArray().ToList();

        foreach (var letter in oneList /* the principal */)
        {
            if (twoList.Contains(letter))
            {
                check++;
            }
        }
        if (check == twoList.Count)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!